# Unable to install puppeteer

Tags: npm, puppeteer, npm-install, npm-publish, npm-request

I have written the command

```
npm i --location=global puppeteer
```

to install puppeteer. writing

```
npm install -g puppeteer
```

also produce the same error:

```
C:\windows\system32>npm install -g puppeteer
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\NITU PANDEL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\NITUPA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\install6572787965.cmd
npm ERR! ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r1011831! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND storage.googleapis.com
npm ERR!     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26) {
npm ERR!   errno: -3008,
npm ERR!   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
npm ERR!   hostname: 'storage.googleapis.com'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NITU PANDEL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-08T11_02_45_016Z-debug-0.log
```

At first it successfully got installed and was able to run the code, but after a day it started to produce the above errors.

I tried everything available on Google.

Comment: That looks like a DNS issue. Does `nslookup storage.googleapis.com` work ok for you?

Comment: If you reset your router / device and retry, does that help?

Comment: I just uninstalled everything, now its working